# Can't integrate JavaFX with Spring Boot in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, javafx

I would like to integrate Spring Boot with JavaFX in IntelliJ environment. I've found [this](http://www.greggbolinger.com/let-spring-be-your-javafx-controller-factory/) article about it.

But it isn't working for me. I have done these steps:

1. Generate plain project using [spring initializer](https://start.spring.io).
2. Import project (Maven project) in IntelliJ
3. Now I can run spring boot application, and it works well.
4. Make changes from the article.
5. Run Spring application action, and then getting errors:

Errors:

> Error:(7, 26) java: package javafX.application does not exist
>       Error:(8, 19) java: package javafx.fxml does not exist
>       Error:(9, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
>       Error:(10, 20) java: package javafx.scene does not exist
>       Error:(11, 20) java: package javafx.stage does not exist
>       Error:(14, 37) java: cannot find symbol symbol: class Application

IntelliJ find sources of JavaFX packages. I can look into JavaFX code. But why cannot compile and run?

Comment: Are you using Java 8 or later?

Comment: Java10. When I create new JavaFX project, it works well.

Comment: Check the java version used by IntelliJ, go to JAVA_HOME/jmods and JAVA_HOME/legal, verify if you have there javafx.* packages. I remember I had a similar issue and had to change java, as for some reason it did not contain JavaFX packages (that was not Java 11). **Solution was** to change java used by IntelliJ for the one which contained this packages.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably caused by IntelliJ which downgrade your java version. Try this solution:

File->Project Structure -> Project and check if Project SDK and Project language level is above 8.

You can also use shortcut: `ctrl + shift + alt + s`